# Get the Maximum Value for each Summed amount in each Stage

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, max

I've searched over this and other sites, but couldn't find the exact example to what I'm looking for.
Basically, I have a Games table (sports, to be precise) and need to sum amounts by user and stage, then get the maximum for each stage.

This is my table:

```
Game_Score_User(GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, Score)
-- Primary key is (GameId, UsrRegId, Stage)
```

Now, I have different GameId's, but I'm filtering by only one.

Then, for this Game (basketball on this example) you can have several matches on a certain Stage. Let's say a stage is played along two days (so date doesn't matter) and you have 6 matches played within it. Your Users will have entered their predictions before those matches were played. Then, depending on their successed or failed predictions, they will earn some score.(this is done by a program, but I want to explain what's the purpose of this table)

Ok, now we have for each User, some score within a certain Stage. So if we have User 200 and user 240, they MAY have score for those stages (depending if they predicted for any game within that stage or not, otherwise, they get score = 0 for that match or stage respectively).

My understanding is, as you cannot do a MAX(SUM()), you need to solve the SUM within a query, then assign an alias to it, so you can work with it as if it was an actual table, then from that "table" ask for the MAX() value for the field you want, grouping by the correct fields.

I'm guessing I'm grouping by unnecessary values in the sub-query but... if I don't include those attributes in the sub-query for my "table" with alias, then I can't refer to those attributes from the "external" or "main" query. Am I wright? I say this because I get an error telling me that/those attribute/s doesn't/don't exist in that case.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Bottom line is I need to get GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, and accumulated score in a result from a query which should tell me ***who won each Stage***.

What I have tried so far is the following query, but it only gives me the added score but not the maximum for each stage. I.e., it only tells me the total for each Stage AND user, instead of telling me "this stage was won by this user":

```
  SELECT JPU.GameId, JPU.UsrRegId, JPU.Stage, MAX(JPU.Score_User) as Winner_Score
  FROM (SELECT GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, SUM(Points) as Score_User
        FROM Game_Score_User
        WHERE GameId = 280 AND
              Stage IN (SELECT Stage
                        FROM Game_Stages 
                        WHERE GameId = 280)
        GROUP BY GameId, UsrRegId, Stage) JPU
  GROUP BY JPU.GameId, JPU.UsrRegId, JPU.Stage
```

Comment: After reading your wall of text it sounds like all you need to do is SELECT TOP 1 JPU.GameId, JPU.Score_User AS Winner_Score FROM ... then remove the GROUP BY and replace it with ORDER BY JPU.Score_User DESC ?

Comment: Thanks both of you. In response to @RichardHansell, that's not exactly what I'm looking for, and it's my fault for such a long question, so I'll rephrase it as per George Stocker's request. I'll explain it with sets theory: I have a set of Stages. Within each Stage, I have several Users with their score for each match they predicted. So I need to get the total Score for each User for each Stage. Then, I need to compare the Score of each user against each other, to get the maximum score from each stage. I should end having the winner user of each stage.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, please let me know if my question is more understandable now. I'm trying to explain my idea as detailed as possible but at the same time, not in a way that sounds complicated.

Comment: @JavierDissimoz You [could cut out about 75% of the explaining](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/26979.html) and still be left with an understandable question.

Comment: Ok, let me try again. I have 4 columns which are important: GameId, UserId, Stage, Score. What I'm trying to achieve is get the Score that earned each User on each Stage. Then, based on those results, get the maximum score earned on each Stage, thus, knowing who is the User who won that Stage. I'm describing it in two steps as I think it should be solved. Maybe I'm confusing everyone because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so let's back it up a little bit and start with your subquery.

```
SELECT GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, SUM(Points) as Score_User
        FROM Game_Score_User
        WHERE GameId = 280 AND
              Stage IN (SELECT Stage
                        FROM Game_Stages 
                        WHERE GameId = 280)
        GROUP BY GameId, UsrRegId, Stage
```

The `stage in (...)` doesn't actually filter anything out of the subquery. It's essentially saying that the gameid must be 280 and the stage must be from a game that has gameid 280. If the stage didn't correlate to the gameId, then it shouldn't be in the Game_Score_User table. In other words, we shouldn't let Johnny place a bet that Steve will beat Chris if Steve and Chris aren't playing any games together.

```
SELECT GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, SUM(Points) as Score_User
FROM Game_Score_User
WHERE GameId = 280
GROUP BY GameId, UsrRegId, Stage
```

This portion of your subquery will return the list of total userscores and the game and stage they are associated to. Let's say this query returns the following data:

> ```
> GameID | UsrRegID | Stage | Score_User
> 280    | 1        | 1     | 20
> 280    | 1        | 3     | 4
> 280    | 2        | 1     | 15
> 280    | 2        | 2     | 15
> 280    | 2        | 3     | 15
> 280    | 3        | 2     | 25
> 280    | 4        | 1     | 17
> 280    | 4        | 3     | 12
> ```

Now we need to filter this table down to the rows that have the greatest score_user for each stage. The problem with how you are approaching this is that if you want to pull back the GameID, UsrRegId, Stage, and Score_User, you can't just tell sql to grab the max(score_user) and group by all of those columns. It will pull back the same results that I have listed above. A group by will no longer help solve the problem because all of the data is already grouped correctly.

Unfortunately, the only way to really do this is with a self join and we are going to have to aggregate the sum again to make sure the row we are looking at is the max. There are several ways to do this, I personally prefer a not exists.

```
SELECT JPU.GameId, JPU.UsrRegId, JPU.Stage, JPU.Score_User as Winner_Score
FROM (SELECT GameId, UsrRegId, Stage, SUM(Points) as Score_User
        FROM Game_Score_User gsu
        WHERE GameId = 280
        GROUP BY GameId, UsrRegId, Stage) gsu
Where not exists (Select *
                    From Game_Score_User gsu2
                    WHERE GameId = 280
                    and gsu2.Stage = gsu.Stage
                    GROUP BY GameId, UsrRegId, Stage
                    Having sum(gsu2.points) > gsu.Score_User)
```

The not exists makes sure that there isn't any score that is greater than the current row. The having is a way to compare aggregate functions and in this case I am using it to check the other sums of the scores for the gameid and stage. not exists only returns true if the results table is empty. This query should result in:

> ```
> GameID | UsrRegID | Stage | Score_User
> 280    | 1        | 1     | 20
> 280    | 2        | 3     | 15
> 280    | 3        | 2     | 25
> ```

Comment: Excellent @Jenn !! That was exactly what I was looking for. I was really wrong trying to re-group data, now I see why I always ended with "separated" data insted of finally "summarizing" everything to get just the winner of each stage. I had to read your explanation three times to understand the concepts, because my weak point is these kind of operations. You can consider this question as solved. Thank you all!